# Loading a Java class on worklight server startup

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, startup

I want to load a few keys from keystore file. I have written a java class to load these keys and calling this class from adapter for signing. How can I load a Java class on worklight server startup?

I am using worklight 6.0

Answer (score 1):

By placing the Java file in the [your-project]\conf\server\java folder, this file is then merged and available from the project's .war file. It will essentially be available on server startup so that once the request to the adapter arrives, the code will be available for the adapter to then execute.